# PHPExcel function getHighestRow() is NOT working for .xls but working for .xlsx

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using **PHPExcel** to read its content based on no.of rows present.

To find no.of rows I am using following function.

```
$objSheet->getHighestRow();
```

It is working fine for .xlsx files.

But it is **NOT** working  in .xls.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestRow() on a non-object

So how i can get no.of rows of excel ?

PHP Code:

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include 'www/PHPExcelReader/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    include 'www/PHPExcelReader/Classes/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    try {
        $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite3;
        PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("Sheet1") );
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $no_of_rows=$objSheet->getHighestRow();
        //echo "no_of_rows=$no_of_rows";
```

I want both xls & .xlsx to be supported... Please guide me.

Comment: The PHPExcel getHighestRow() method shouldn't care whether cells are protected or not! If it does, then it's a major flaw in the PHPExcel code, that needs fixing rather than a workround. As I'm trying to release a new version this weekend, can you please raise an issue for this on the [PHPExcel codeplex site](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced), providing a sample spreadsheet file that demonstrates this problem so that I can look at fixing it

Comment: @MarkBaker : I updated the question with error log as well.. please have a look. `Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestRow() on a non-object`

Comment: Is this using Excel2007 Reader, Excel5 Reader or any Reader?

Comment: @MarkBaker : I updated the question. its due to xls file type . Please suggest a solution.

Comment: @MarkBaker : it is using Excel2007 but i may upload xls & xlsx files.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the problem at the moment..... until I can identify the cause, I can't provide any fix or suggest any workround.... but the problem isn't related to the `getHighestRow()` method... how are you defining `$objSheet` because it isn't a `PHPExcel_Worksheet` object? Otherwise, `getHighestRow()` would work.

Comment: @MarkBaker : I have updated my code . Please have a look and let me know

Comment: Still unable to replicate the problem; can you raise an issue and provide a sample spreadsheet file that demonstrates the problem to the [codeplex PHPExcel issues](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced) page

Comment: The only way I can replicate this problem is if I set `$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("Sheet1") );` to name a worksheet that doesn't exist in the spreadsheet file

Comment: @MarkBaker: I have replicated this problem by saving Excel as 2003 version in MSOffice 2007; If save the same file with .xlsx it is working. Sheet name and all same...

Comment: @MarkBaker : please see my answer to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem myself.
It is due excel version incompatibility.

Here is the code to resolve this issue.

```
/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
```

Comment: Yes, this is why PHPExcel has different readers for different formats, and why the `PHPExcel_IOFactory` class provides an `identify()` method to determine what reader should be used for any given file, and a generic `load()` method that will determine the format and load it without your needing to identify it

Comment: @MarkBaker : Can you please provide the syntax of load() ?

Comment: The code for `load()` is available in the source code of the library, if you want, you can actually look and see how it works; and there's a whole document detailing all the options for reading spreadsheet data in the /Documentation folder or online at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files

Comment: It also isn't a good idea relying on the file extension to determine what Reader to use, because a lot of people give csv or html markup files an extension of .xls or .xlsx.... the identify() method tests against the actual content of a file rather than simply relying on the file extension being correct